# Sum of products of elements of all subarrays of length k

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

An array of length **n** is given. Find the sum of products of elements of the sub-array.

**Explanation**

Array **A** = **[2, 3, 4]** of length **3**.

Sub-array of length **2** = [2,3], [3,4], [2,4]

Product of elements in **[2, 3]** = 6

Product of elements in **[3, 4]** = 12

Product of elements in **[2, 4]** = 8

Sum for subarray of length **2** = 6+12+8 = 26

Similarly, for length **3**, Sum = 24

As, products can be larger for higher lengths of sub-arrays calculate in modulo **1000000007**.

What is an efficient way for finding these sums for subarrays of all possible lengths, i.e., 1, 2, 3, ......, n where **n** is the length of the array.

Comment: Is it for all sub-arrays or just for sub-arrays of length 2?

Comment: Sum is calculated for sub-arrays of all possible lengths 1, 2, 3, ......, n .

Comment: Constraint on `n` and `k`?

Comment: @MetaD That's a shame, for 2 it's really simple :) (`n` additions, `n` subtractions and `n` multiplications)

Comment: n and k can go upto 1000.

Comment: @biziclop Yes, for 2 it is simple but for high values, it's quite tedious.

Comment: by efficient you mean some less than the obvious `O(n^3)`? Is `O(n^2)` agreeable?

Comment: If, as in your example, the 'sub-arrays' are not sub-sequences of the array but include the non-contiguous ones too, there are n!/k!(n-k)! sub-arrays and you are performing k operations on them, it seems unlikely you will find a O(n*k) solution.

Comment: @PeteKirkham If you look carefully though, you'll find that the same operations are performed again and again, which is why dynamic programming can greatly reduce time complexity.

Comment: @biziclop yes, but if you are calculating sums of combinations for k from 1 to N you will be hitting every combination, so that's at least 2^N operations just for summation, assuming you have no cost in calculating the products. So far most the answers are only summing (n-k) terms not n!/k!(n-k)! terms as per the example above.

Comment: @PeteKirkham That is true. As an aside though, suddenly the requirement to give the answer mod 1000000007 (a well-known prime number:)) appeared too, which changes the whole nature of the problem.

Comment: @MetaD Is it a project euler exercise ? In case it is an online problem can you provide the link ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We first create a recursive relation. Let `f(n, k)` be the sum of all products of sub-arrays of length `k` from an array `a` of length `n`. The base cases are simple:

```
f(0, k) = 0 for all k
f(n, 0) = 1 for all n
```

The second rule might seem a little counter-intuitive, but 1 is the zero-element of multiplication.

Now we find a recursive relation for `f(n+1, k)`. We want the product of all subarrays of size `k`. There are two types of subarrays here: the ones including `a[n+1]` and the ones not including `a[n+1]`. The sum of the ones not including `a[n+1]` is exactly `f(n, k)`. The ones including `a[n+1]` are exactly all subarrays of length `k-1` with `a[n+1]` added, so their summed product is `a[n+1] * f(n, k-1)`.

This completes our recurrence relation:

```
f(n, k) = 0                               if n = 0
        = 1                               if k = 0
        = f(n-1, k) + a[n] * f(n-1, k-1)  otherwise
```

---

You can use a neat trick to use very limited memory for your dynamic programming, because function `f` only depends on two earlier values:

```
int[] compute(int[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    int[] f = int[N];
    f[0] = 1;

    for (int n = 1; n < N; n++) {
        for (int k = n; k >= 1; k--) {
            f[k] = (f[k] + a[n] * f[k-1]) % 1000000007;
        }
    }

    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is rather simple way:
Construct product of terms `(1 + A[i] * x)`:

```
P = (1 + A[0] * x) * (1 + A[1] * x) * (1 + A[2] * x)...*(1 + A[n-1] * x)
```

If we open the brackets, then we'll get polynomial

```
P = 1 + B[1] * x + B[2] * x^2 + ... + B[n] * x^n
```

Kth coefficient, B[k], is equal to the sum of products of sets with length K - for example, `B[n] = A[0]*A[1]*A[2]*..A[n-1], B[2] = A[0]*A[1] + A[0]*A[2] + ... + A[n-2]*A[n-1]` and so on.

So to find sum of products of all possible sets, we have to find value of polynomial P for x = 1, then subtract 1 to remove leading 0th term. If we don't want to take into consideration single-element sets, then subtract B1 = sum of A[i].

Example:

```
(1+2)(1+3)(1+4) = 60
60 - 1 = 59
59 - (2 + 3 + 4) = 50 = 24 + 26 - as your example shows
```

Comment: I didn't read the problem correctly. I thought we needed the sum for each `k` separately. This is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: If all we want is the sum of all products over all nonempty subsets, then this should be the most efficient way to do it. If we want the partial sums (i.e. those for fixed-size subsets), then I don't see how to extract them from this.