# Sum of elementwise product of subsets' min of two arrays

Tags: dynamic-programming, deque

As the title suggests, writing the question explicitly could create some confusion. So, I start by an example.

Let's say we have two arrays: a = [1,3,2] and [5,4,3]. What I would like compute in a brute-force way is to first compute the minimum of each of the subset as:

```
aa = [1, 3, 2, min(1,3), min(1,2), min(3,2), min(1,3,2)]
bb = [5, 4, 6, min(5,4), min(5,6), min(4,6), min(5,4,6)]
```

and then finally the sum of the product aa ** bb:

```
1*5 + 3*4 + 2*6 + min(1,3)*min(5,4) + min(1,2) * min(5,6) +  min(3,2)*min(4,6) + min(1,3,2)*min(5,4,6)
```

Obviously, the brute-force calculation is not efficient, and the memory and time complexity increase exponentially with respect to the number of elements in the arrays.

To give a bit more context, the arrays could be of real numbers (positive and negatives), and each element in the first array corresponds to the element with the same index in the second array.

I have already seen some similar problems, like:

[Sum of OR of smallest and largest elements of each subset of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323145/sum-of-or-of-smallest-and-largest-elements-of-each-subset-of-a-set?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Sum of products of elements of all subarrays of length k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946724/sum-of-products-of-elements-of-all-subarrays-of-length-k)

But they are mainly focused on sum of the min of subsets for one array only.

Comment: *"Obviously, the brute-force calculation is not efficient, and the memory and time complexity increase exponentially with respect to the number of elements in the arrays."* The time, yes, but the memory, no, not if you perform the sum "online" while iterating on the subsets without storing the subsets in memory.

Comment: Thanks, @stef! you are right! I meant the way I wrote the solution, the memory consumption grows exponentially, but it could indeed be performed 'online' as you said. Any solution for time efficiency?